# Does Geb support multi browser testing?

Tags: grails, gradle, spock, geb

I would like to ask if Geb supports multi browser testing. i.e. testing same scenario at a time in two different browser on one execution?

Answer (score 1):

geb is built on top of [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) which supports most browsers. See [here](https://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/how-to-configure-webdriver-in-grails-for-your-geb-tests/) for geb config for various browsers

Answer (score 0):

I just posted and example app for this. you can create a gradel task to spin through and execute the tests for each browser in the gebconfig. Firefox is a bit of a mess at the moment. link why is provided in the sample gebconfig
https://github.com/basejump/grails3-geb-example

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference